# How to make changes to the Oslo Site Layout

Tags: style, oslo

I am using the Oslo Site Layout on my site. I need to be able to remove the "Home" link that is currently the "Page Title" in the default homepage. How can I remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether you wish to hide the page title or the "Home" from the navigation row, but either way here are the CSS for those:

**Hiding the page title:**

```
h1#pageTitle {
display: none;
}
```

**Hiding the "Home" from the navigation row:**

```
ul#zz15_RootAspMenu li:first-child {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: I tried to upload a screenshot, but it wouldn't show. I'm referring to the "Home" link that appears in the body of the page when using the Oslo site layout.

Comment: Can you tell me where to edit the CSS for this particular item?

Comment: @cbbrown If you want to make the change to only one page of your site, you should use e.g. a Script Editor Web Part or a Content Editor Web Part to embed the snippet including the CSS. Remember to wrap it with `<style></style>`-elements. If you want to make the change on site-wide, you should use the CSS as a separate file referred in your custom master page.